# Vue Material - Styling the table buttons?

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I am playing around with [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) and the [Vue Material](https://marcosmoura.github.io/vue-material/#/) components, specifically the [Table component](https://marcosmoura.github.io/vue-material/#/components/table).

What I would like to do is change the colour of the search icon/button within the table example which is titled `Within cards with Pagination and Inline Edit` but it seems that I must be missing something because I can not get it to change from the default of colour of grey and I am battling to understand why this is the case.

I have a basic page where I have included Vue along with the fonts and icons required for Vue material and the Javascript and CSS files that are required for it to work.

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/marcosmoura/vue-material/master/dist/vue-material.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app" v-md-theme="'default'">
    <md-table-card>
      <md-toolbar>
        <h1 class="md-title">Nutrition</h1>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button">
          <md-icon>filter_list</md-icon>
        </md-button>

        <md-button class="md-icon-button" @click="toggleSearch()">
          <md-icon v-if="searchEnabled" class="md-accent">search</md-icon>
          <md-icon v-else>search</md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </md-toolbar>

      <md-table md-sort="dessert" md-sort-type="desc" @select="onSelect" @sort="onSort">
        <md-table-header>
          <md-table-row>
            <md-table-head md-sort-by="dessert">Dessert (100g serving)</md-table-head>
            <md-table-head md-sort-by="calories" md-numeric md-tooltip="The total amount of food energy and the given serving size">Calories (g)</md-table-head>
            <md-table-head md-sort-by="fat" md-numeric>Fat (g)</md-table-head>
            <md-table-head md-sort-by="carbs" md-numeric>Carbs (g)</md-table-head>
            <md-table-head md-sort-by="protein" md-numeric>Protein (g)</md-table-head>
            <md-table-head>
              <md-icon>message</md-icon>
              <span>Comments</span>
            </md-table-head>
          </md-table-row>
        </md-table-header>

        <md-table-body>
          <md-table-row v-for="(row, rowIndex) in nutrition" :key="rowIndex" :md-item="row" md-auto-select md-selection>
            <md-table-cell v-for="(column, columnIndex) in row" :key="columnIndex" :md-numeric="columnIndex !== 'dessert' && columnIndex !== 'comment'" v-if="columnIndex !== 'type'">
              <md-table-edit
                :md-name="'comment' + columnIndex"
                :md-id="'comment' + columnIndex"
                md-placeholder="Add a comment"
                md-maxlength="120"
                v-model="nutrition[rowIndex].comment"
                v-if="columnIndex === 'comment'"></md-table-edit>

              <span v-if="columnIndex !== 'comment'"></span>
            </md-table-cell>
          </md-table-row>
        </md-table-body>
      </md-table>

      <md-table-pagination
        md-size="10"
        md-total="5"
        md-page="1"
        md-label="Rows"
        md-separator="of"
        :md-page-options="[5, 10, 25, 50]"
        @pagination="onPagination"></md-table-pagination>
    </md-table-card>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/marcosmoura/vue-material/master/dist/vue-material.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**:

```
// Enable Vue Material
Vue.use(VueMaterial);

// Apply theme
Vue.material.theme.register('default', {
  primary: 'blue',
  accent: 'light-blue'
});

// Initialise Vue
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nutrition: [{
      dessert: 'Frozen yogurt',
      type: 'ice_cream',
      calories: '159',
      fat: '6.0',
      carbs: '24',
      protein: '4.0',
      comment: 'Icy'
    }],
    selectedData: [],
    sort: {},
    page: {},
    searchEnabled: false
  },
  methods: {
    onSelect: function (data) {
      this.selectedData = data;
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
    onSort: function (sort) {
      this.sort = sort;
    },
    onPagination: function (page) {
      this.page = page;
    },
    toggleSearch: function () {
      console.log(this.searchEnabled);
      if (this.searchEnabled) {
        this.searchEnabled = false;
      } else {
        this.searchEnabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When I load the page I get the application with the table as with the example. When I click on the search icon, I can see the console log from the method `toggleSearch()` and it changes between boolean values as expected, however, the colour of the search icon is not changing.

Looking at the components HTML for the search button:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" @click="toggleSearch()">
  <md-icon v-if="searchEnabled" class="md-accent">search</md-icon>
  <md-icon v-else>search</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

I used a if / else condition to switch between the accented class and what I assume would be the default grey depending on the boolen value `searchEnabled` and this works with a stand alone button but just not inside of the table.

Could anyone suggest a reason as to why this is happening or how I should be going about styling of this button within the table. Any input or feedback would be greatly appreciated, many thanks!

(Bonus points if you can suggest if there is a way in Vue to apply a class conditionally, i.e. instead of using `v-if`, `v-else` and duplicating the icon element, is there another way for me to apply the class based on the boolean value and use only one icon element?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can do dynamic styling using VueJs, [Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) is documentation for the same. You can pass an object to `v-bind:class` to dynamically toggle classes:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" @click="toggleSearch()">
  <md-icon v-bind:class="{ 'md-accent': searchEnabled }">search</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

The above syntax means the presence of the `md-accent` class will be determined by the truthiness of the data property `searchEnabled`.

Comment: Bonus points achieved :-) Thank you, that works well but still not working within the Vue Material table for the search button. Any ideas why or does it seem like a bug to you?

Comment: Was going to do a small edit but cannot, you need to change the quotes for `"md-accent"` to single quotes `'md-accent'`.

Comment: @CraigvanTonder Done, thanks for pointing out. Also this is the search button I have in answer which is not working or that is different?

Comment: See the magnifying glass that is top right in the second example here: https://marcosmoura.github.io/vue-material/#/components/table ~ The code that you have given works for other buttons but not when styling this button in the Vue Material table and that is my question directly. Wondering now if it is a bug as it seems like it should just work but I only get a grey icon as in the docs example.

Comment: may be the CSS property you are trying to change is being overwritten, You may have to write a new class with `!important` for that CSS property.

Comment: It was a good idea, I tried that but still nothing. The class just does not get applied when the component is rendered, it should as it does normally so I am guessing that it's a bug and will make an issue for it instead.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that was fixed in v0.4.0

Comment: Giving @saurabh the answer as his solution covers how to style the button if there was no bug affecting things.